# Items, texts and lists are blurred

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I tested my application on two different Android devices and in both the exact same problem occurs. When it is clicked, the scroll is occupied, it is typed in inputs, the texts are lost, they are blurred, the lists also, their items and everything is still blurred. Start my application, exactly the same on an Iphone device, 5, 5s, 6, 6plus, 6s and 7 and in no problem occurs.

In the following images you can clearly see the difference of the texts and in fact, in the images do not look as bad as live occupying the application in the device.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with declaring in your manifest to support screens of different sizes and dpi. Try adding this to your manifest outside of the application tags.

```
<supports-screens 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"
android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="320"/>
```

Comment: And in ionic I modify the manifest that is in the folder platform?

Comment: Hmm, Im not entirely sure. I did some reading and it seems that there should be a platforms folder for android with a manifest xml inside. Sorry, Im not experienced with ionic, but Im almost sure that it will solve your issue if you can find and add that to the manifest.

Comment: I did, but the same problem remains

Comment: @sioesi hmm, then it must be some issue with ionic.